# Formula to format a cell to subtract one decimal place from another cell and have the calculated results displayed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I have  a value in one cell that has four decimal places, in the cell below, I have the metric conversion formula.  I want the cell below, with the metric conversion formula to display one less decimal place than the cell above.

For example, if the English measurement is .#### (4 decimal places), I need the conversion cell to display .### (3 decimal places) and if the English measurement is .### (3 decimal places), I need the conversion cell to display .### ( decimal places), and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: You question is all run together and difficult to follow. If I understand you correctly, the cell above has 4 decimal places and you want the cell below it to have 3. All you have to do is set the formatting of the cell to 3 decimal places. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CharlieRB I think that if `A1` has `x` decimal places, `A2` needs to have `x-1` decimal places.

Comment: Thank you for the formula help, I want to set the below cell to always reduce the decimal places by 1. I will check out the formula with my team and advise how we made out. I think the problem is we have the metric conversion formula set up in the below cell and cannot write the formula to incorporate the decimal place reduction.
i.e Cell B9 .2500 Cell B10 [6.35] formula in Cell B10 is =("["&(B9*25.4)&"]")

Answer (score 0):

You could work based on the following:

```
=(INT(A1)&"."&MID(MOD(A1,1),FIND(".",MOD(A1,1))+1,LEN(MOD(A1,1))-(LEN(INT(A1))+1)-1))+0
```

Copy down as far as desired. This will just cut off decimals, though.

[image]

If you want to round the values, use a helper cell for the conversion formula and round the result with something along these lines:

```
=ROUND(D2,(LEN(D1)-LEN(INT(D1)))-2)
```

In the following screenshot the formula is in cell D3

[image]